# Collect Closing prices column from many data frame

Tags: dataframe

I have a list of stocks. stocks can be any number but for simplicity I take three stocks. I want to make a new data frame with closing prices of all stocks present in the stocks.

"stocks = [chcc, trg, efert]"

I want to take Closing prices of the each of the stock from stocks.